# Bare minimum configuration needed to deploy an app with capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, vps

Is this the bare minimum amount of options needed to deploy an application stored in a repo on my local development machine?

```
# config/deploy.rb
set :scm, "git" # is this necessary?
set :user, "deployer"  # is this the username of my vps? How do I set the password?
set :deploy_to, "/rails_apps" # will this install the app to the /deployer/rails_apps directory of my ubuntu vps?
```

I still don't know how to specify the ip of my vps, or the password.

I've noticed that the config file is huge..why would I need to specify any more options than this? What more would I possibly want to do once the app is online?

Comment: > I've noticed that the config file is huge..why would I need to specify any more options than this? What more would I possibly want to do once the app is online?

What config file?

Comment: Cap3 doesn't support what you are trying to do, perhaps you'd be better with a standard rake/make job to do a simple rsync.

Comment: Maybe...I do see how it would be cool installing from an online repo. This is my first VPS, I think I had the wrong end of the stick regarding best practises when deploying apps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Getting Started](http://www.capistranorb.com/) section on the capistrano homepage offers great documentation on a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the bare minimum amount of options needed to deploy an application stored in a repo on my local development machine?

That's not possible with Capistrano 3. See [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).